# How to detect test device after uploading appbundle to Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

My app allows anonymous users to click buttons that call my API. I want to filter out test devices that are app crawling. They don't seem to be part of Firebase Test Lab. Steps:

1. Start new app release in Google Play Console.
2. Upload app bundle in the section "Android App Bundles and APKs to add".
3. Wait approximately five minutes. DO NOT proceed to step 2 "Review and roll-out".
4. Check my server logs.
5. There are calls from android MTC20F (reported by dart:io [Platform](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-io/Platform-class.html)) on multiple IPs e.g.

   - 64.233.172.32
   - 66.249.88.64
   - 74.125.210.33
6. The [Firebase Test Lab system variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for) is null.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, when the app is being reviewed/ran on test servers for Google Play, I noticed a curious side effect, which is that I cannot access the cache dir for listing on Android:

```
FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/data/user/0/my.package.name/cache/random_folder/' (OS Error: Invalid argument, errno = 22)
```

The code that causes this error is:

```
Future<List<File>> getFilesInDirectory(String directoryPath) async {
  // `directoryPath` is fetched on Android side with `context.cacheDir`
  final cacheDir = Directory(directoryPath);

  final files = <File>[];
  // This call succeeds, .. I still don't get why :D
  if (!cacheDir.existsSync()) return files; 

  final completer = Completer();
  // Tries to list all files in the folder
  cacheDir.list(followLinks: false).listen(
    (file) {
      if (file is! File) {
        return;
      }

      files.add(file as File);
    },
    onDone: () => completer.complete(),
    onError: (err) {
      log(err) // <---- This is where I get the error
    }
  );
  await completer.future;
  return files;
}
```